# How to get real value of Screen Size in C# WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get Screen width and Height of my System on `SizeChanged` Event.

It works fine in all cases excluding:

1. Change Screen Size to 1024 X 765 then Run my Application its works fine.
2. Change Screen Size Again to Another Resolution while my application running 
   got Width and height of my Previous Resolution not Current.

I have used `screen.primaryscreen.bounds.width` on `Window_SizeChanged` Event.

Comment: Did my answer help any? I know it uses the same property you were using, but it does it within the `SystemEvents` rather than the Window events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monitor the `SystemEvents` for changes.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

Add this to your constructor or the like:

```
SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += 
    new EventHandler(SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged);
```

Here's the event handler. I have the data bound to 2 TextBoxes so I could see the values change as I messed with the resolution, including telling it to revert.

```
  void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     data.ScreenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
     data.ScreenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
  }
```

In your case, just change the assignment to point to where you want to store it.